# Wrap Loki::Typelist with C++11 variadic template

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I am trying to avoid LOKI_TYPELIST_n macros, so I though I can write simple Loki::Typelist wrapper.

```
template <typename...Ts>
struct TYPELIST;

template <>
struct TYPELIST<>
{
    typedef Loki::NullType Result;
};

template <typename HEAD, typename...Ts>
struct TYPELIST<HEAD,Ts...>
{
    typedef Loki::Typelist<HEAD, TYPELIST<Ts...>::Result> Result;
};
```

Upon compilation I get the following error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T, class U> struct Loki::Typelist’
error:   expected a type, got ‘TYPELIST<Ts ...>::Result’
```

I though `TYPELIST<Ts...>::Result` is a type. What is wrong with it?
GCC 4.6.2 here.

I want to use it like this:

```
typedef TYPELIST<
        EventTank1,
        EventTank2,
        EventTank3
    >::Result EVENTS_ALL__;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `typename` word in front of `TYPELIST<Ts ...>::Result`. Just because you know it is a type does not mean that the compiler knows it too (if only!).

Comment: Oh...:( I got lazy with newer versions of GCC suggesting forgotten `typename` in the error messages. Thank you Matthieu.